# Finding matching position of numeric values in R

Tags: r, match

The numeric variable weitage is given like,

```
> weitage
[1] 20 10 50 10  5  5
```

Then,

```
sort_wei<-sort(weitage,decreasing = T)
sort_wei
[1] 50 20 10 10  5  5
match(sort_wei,weitage)
```

results in `3 1 2 2 5 5`. But actually needed position is `3 1 2 4 5 6`. How to get these positions? Can i use `match()` in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using the `order` function, which returns the indices of the input vector according to some sort order:

```
order(weitage, decreasing=TRUE)

#[1] 3 1 2 4 5 6
```